# How to download a trackerless torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

I have a somewhat old PC at home, and I would like to try to extend its useful life with a linux distro. Reading various reviews, I decided that the first one to give a try would be LXLE. However, its download can only be done through a trackerless torrent. Having downloaded the torrent file, I have seen no progress so far, and as some other people had this problem too, I know it has something to do with my settings (e.g. my port 80 is not visible). Can someone give me a brief "tutorial" as to how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the torrent hash from uTorrent:

[image: torrent hash]

And look up the hash on [Torrentz.eu](https://torrentz.eu/). From the search result, download a uTorrent compatible list of trackers by clicking on the `µTorrent compatible list here` link.

[image: tracker list]

Then in uTorrent,  update the torrent properties to add those trackers to the list.

[image: torrent properties]

After that, the trackers should auto update and if there are any seeds or peers available, you should be able to see them in the `Trackers` tab.

[image: seeds and peers]

**NOTE:**

LXLE's website however does state that they use trackless torrents and after waiting for a while to find peers, the download should start.

> LXLE torrents currently do not utilize a third party tracker, unless
>   specified by the seeder, to respect user rights. Therefore the
>   torrents may take slightly longer to start, its also likely it will
>   not report any seeders only peers, this is the nature of a trackerless
>   torrent. Make sure your torrent ports are open and be patient, once
>   peers are found download speeds are quick.